# What is the recommended max message size in Hazelcast?

Tags: java, publish-subscribe, hazelcast

I'm trying to understand the recommended max message size in Hazelcast. The best documentation I can find is https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.0/capacity-planning where it says

> An optimum partition size is between 50MB – 100MB

Does this mean messages should be smaller in size than that limit?  Is there a way I can pass around messages that are 1Gb in size?  Is this recommended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't recommended to have very large messages. A few hundred KB; would really be the maximum. I guess a few MB will still work, but Hazelcast isn't really designed for large payloads.

There is currently no solution to pass huge messages. Perhaps you use a different storage mechanism like an S3 bucket and just send the reference through HZ.